# Advice on using display:none to hide elements and also remove them completely from DOM

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I am using css media queries on my site and I have used display: none to hide some elements. Although this does the trick in terms of completely hiding the element it still remains in the DOM. Are there any methods that I can use to completely remove the element from the DOM also?

Comment: You want to [`.remove()`](http://api.jquery.com/remove/) from the DOM? Hm, there might be something in jQuery that does that...

Comment: Did you mean how to select the element by the "media-queries" ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`element.parentNode.removeChild(element)` is the universal method to remove DOM nodes from.

The JQuery method: `$("selector").remove()`

Example:

```
<body>
    <div id="foo"></div>
</div>

JavaScript:
    var element = document.getElementById("foo");
    element.parentNode.removeChild(element);

jQuery equivalent:
    $("#foo").remove();

Result:
    <body></body>
```